# Enum case '...' is not a member of type '...'

Tags: ios, swift

I have an enum:

```
enum State {
    case FullOpen
    case HalfOpen
    case Closed
}
```

and this code:

```
var stateForConversionView: State!
...


var previousState: State!

if true {
    previousState = stateForConversionView!
    switch previousState {
    case .FullOpen:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    case .HalfOpen:
        stateForConversionView = .FullOpen
    case .Closed:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I got an error on each switch statement:

```
Enum case 'FullOpen' not found in type 'State!'
Enum case 'HalfOpen' not found in type 'State!'
Enum case 'Closed' not found in type 'State!'
```

I don't really understand why. Can someone explain me please?

Comment: Basically it's not recommended to declare enum type variables as any kind of optionals because an enum is designed to have always a defined state.

Comment: Event  if it is implicitly unwrap optional `State!`, you still need to add `!`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This way It will work fine :

```
if true {
    previousState = stateForConversionView

    switch previousState! {
    case .FullOpen:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    case .HalfOpen:
        stateForConversionView = .FullOpen
    case .Closed:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

You need to add `!`.

For more info refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670991/why-force-unwrapping-is-required-in-case-of-enum-and-switch).

Comment: ... I forgot this one... Thanks :)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Was hoping if you could clarify for me: if `previousState` is declared as unwrapped, why would he need to unwrap again in the `switch` to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig you can fond its Reason by this link: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/

Comment: > `You need to add !` < I'd be interested in hearing *why* `!` is needed as part of this answer.

Comment: As Unheilig, I also wonder why this explicit unwrapping is necessary when it was declared as unwrapped. Maybe @mattt can explain this to us?

Comment: I'd also/still be interested why the unwrapping is necessary when the variable is declared as `state: State!` (i.e. unwrapped).

Comment: How annoying, because in my switch statement the enum value is a constant i.e. let configProperty: MyEnum!

Comment: ugh, damn you Swift!  Stuff like this is so crap.

Comment: I was also curious about why this was the case and I found this other answer on SO -- figured I would link it here in case anyone else comes across this solution and wonders why the seemingly redundant unwrapping is necessary @pkamb

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670991/why-force-unwrapping-is-required-in-case-of-enum-and-switch

Answer (score 3):

If the condition variable is in a different type of the "State". You should use rawValue property.

```
var previousState:String
previousState = stateForConversionView
 switch previousState {
        case State.FullOpen.rawValue:
            stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
        case State.HalfOpen.rawValue:
            stateForConversionView = .FullOpen
        case State.Closed.rawValue:
            stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
        default:break

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `?` at the end of case state.

```
if true {
    previousState = stateForConversionView

    switch previousState {
    case .FullOpen?:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    case .HalfOpen?:
        stateForConversionView = .FullOpen
    case .Closed?:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

or `.some(Error)`

```
if true {
    previousState = stateForConversionView

    switch previousState {
    case .some(.FullOpen):
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    case .some(.HalfOpen):
        stateForConversionView = .FullOpen
    case .some(.Closed):
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to create a temporary variable(`previousState`). Just unwrap the property that you are using as enum:

```
if true {
    switch stateForConversionView! {
    case .FullOpen:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    case .HalfOpen:
        stateForConversionView = .FullOpen
    case .Closed:
        stateForConversionView = .HalfOpen
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not exactly the same answer than @DharmeshKheni because it's not necessary to create a temporary variable and unwrap it to solve the problem. You only need to unwrap the property that you are using as enum.

Comment: The variable is not temporary, it's a simplified example.

Comment: @Sulthan what is that?

`...
previousState = stateForConversionView

switch previousState! {
...`

When something is simplified when you have to write more code?

I saw that and I realised in my implementation that I don't need to do it. That's why I wrote this answer. Also, you save CPU and Memory even when it's a very very little.