# Why force unwrapping is required in case of enum and switch?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have notice weird swift behaviour, because in my opinion colours variable shouldn't be force unwrapped in case of switch written below, but without unwrapping compiler shows me an error message.

```
enum Colours: Int {
case Red = 0, White, Black
}

var colours: Colours!
colours = .Red

switch colours! { // <-- why I have to unwrap colours? As you can see colours are declared as '!'
case .Red: break
default: break
}
```

if colours variable is not unwrapped compiler shows me that error:
[image]

in my opinion it is swift inconsistency, does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update:** This has been fixed in **Swift 5.1.**  From the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> [SR-7799](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7799):
>
> Enum cases can now be matched against an optional enum without requiring a '?' at the end of the pattern.

This applies to your case of implicitly unwrapped optionals as well:

```
var colours: Colours!

switch colours {
case .red:
    break    // colours is .red
default:
    break    // colours is .white, .black or nil
}
```

---

*Previous answer:*

When used in a `switch` statement,  even implicitly unwrapped
optionals are *not* automatically unwrapped. (A reason might be that you
could not match them against `nil` otherwise.)

So you have to unwrap (either forcibly with
`colours!` which will crash if `colours == nil`, or with optional binding), or – alternatively – match against `.Red?`
which is a shortcut for `.Some(.Red)`:

```
var colours: Colours!

switch colours {
case .Red?:
    break    // colours is .Red
default:
    break    // colours is .White, .Black or nil
}
```

The same holds for other pattern-matching expressions, e.g.

```
if case .Red? = colours {
    // colours is .Red 
} else {
    // colours is .White, .Black or nil
}
```

Also this has nothing to do with enumeration types, only with implicitly
unwrapped optionals in a pattern:

```
let x : Int! = 1

switch x {
case nil:
    break // x is nil
case 1?:
    break // x is 1
default:
    break // x is some other number
}
```

Comment: A few of your `colours` are `colors` ;-)

Comment: Yes!  Autocorrection was correcting my comment as well.  The blame may really belong with Noah Webster though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you create `colours` variable like optional type. If you do like this:

```
var colours: Colours
colours = .Red
```

you will not have to unwrappe this value

If we look at what the optional type is, we will see that this is enum like:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case Some(T)
    case None
}
```

And it can be `Some` Type like `Int` for example or `None` and in this case it's have nil value.

When you make this:

```
var colours: Colours!
```

you directly is indicated by the `!` that this is not `Colours` type but this is the `enum ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Colours>` type. At moment of creation it's will be `Some<Colours>` if equal it value but with this `!` you have that it is `enum ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Colours>` and in some next moment it will be the `None`. That's why you have to use `!` in `switch`:

Your `colours` value is `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Colours>` type and it may be `Colours` or `nil` and you have to directly indicate that this is `Colours` type in `switch``.

Comment: Could you provide some documentation showing that declaring a variable with `!` makes it optional?

Comment: `colors` has the type `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Colours>`, not `Optional<Colours>`.

Comment: @MartinR Yes you are right, I corrected it, thank you for comment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using :

```
var colours: Colours!
colours = .Red
```

Simply use

```
var colours = Colours.Red
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: But I want to have optional colours variable. It should works without '!' in my opinion.

Comment: @roher Declaring an enum type variable as optional is not very useful since an enum is designed to have a definite state. Use a .`None` state or similar rather than an optional.