# What's wrong with comparing non-optional bool in a single if structure in swift

Tags: swift, mapper

I have been coding in Swift for a while, and I think I had to put a ! on all my let field variables that were not defined immediately.

Now I notice today that this piece of code does not compile and I am really surprised? why is this?

```
class MyClass : Mapper {
    var a: Bool!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        a   <- map["a"]
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()

if myClass.a { // Compiler not happy
    //  Optional type 'Bool!' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead
}

if true && myClass.a { // Compiler happy

}

if myClass.a && myClass.a { // Compiler happy

}
```

Apple Swift version 2.2

**Edit**
Some people point out why am I using a `let` for a variable that will never change. I mentioned it is for field variables but I shorten the example. When using ObjectMapper (http://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), all the fields are not defined immediately in the init. This is why they are all either optional? or required!

Comment: In `if` and `switch` statements, implicitly unwrapped optionals aren't automatically force unwrapped (if you just use them on their own). This is so you can safely compare them with `nil`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670991/why-force-unwrapping-is-required-in-case-of-enum-and-switch

Comment: Shortest workaround: `if a! {`

Comment: Wow, this is highly inconsistent and it becomes scary for the code reviewers. They will ask why am I not using an `if let` statement to prevent a crash. If I use `if true && a`, I'll get fired.

Comment: For safety, `if a ?? false {`, which is less weird than `if let a = a where a {`.

Comment: ... and also less ugly than `if case true? = a {` :)

Comment: ... or `if a.boolValue {`

Comment: A `let` property should almost never be an implicitly-unwrapped optional. Change it to a plain `Bool`.

Comment: @dfri, `if a.boolValue {` will crash if `a` is `nil`.  As will `if a as Bool {`.

Comment: @originaluser2 The main reason is the usage of the ObjectMapper https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper . I have to set some properties as ? and other as !.

Comment: @vacawama Indeed; this is likewise true for your own shortest workaround `if a! {` (safety of these workarounds is another discussion, imo; as rob mayoff writes; why even use an implicit unwrapped optional for this case)

Comment: @dfri, I took your ellipsis to mean it was tagging on to the safe suggestions comments.

Comment: @vacawama Ah, I missed that the ellipsis naturally bind to your _"For safety ..."_, I skimmed the previous comments too quickly and just thought we were listing alternatives to avoid the compile time error, my bad!

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with a concrete use-case. Couldn't `a` be `nil` if the object is initialized from some JSON?

Comment: @dfri, no problem.  This has been a fun discussion all around.

Comment: @MartinR Here, I updated the use case. Now the question is completely lost with the usage of a third party library where I was asking a simple Swift question why Swift has to be so strict about if structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of history...

In Swift 1.0, it was possible to check if an optional variable `optVar` contained a value by just checking:

```
if optVar {
    println("optVar has a value")
} else {
    println("optVar is nil")
}
```

In *The Swift Programming Language*, the update for Swift 1.1 (dated 2014-10-16) stated:

> Optionals no longer implicitly evaluate to `true` when they have a value and `false` when they do not, to avoid confusion when working with optional `Bool` values.  Instead, make an explicit check against `nil` with the `==` or `!=` operators to find out if an optional contains a value.

So, the nonsensical error message that you are getting was put there because the *Swift* compiler is interpreting your:

```
if a {
}
```

to mean:

```
if a != nil {
}
```

and it is encouraging you to test against `nil` to determine if the Optional `a` has a value.

Perhaps the Swift authors will change it in the future, but for now you will have to explicitly unwrap `a`:

```
if a! {
}
```

or check against `true`:

```
if a == true {
}
```

or (to be completely safe):

```
if a ?? false {
    print("this will not crash if a is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare `let a: Bool` without a `!` and without declaring true or false right then. The compiler will complain if it can't guarantee the value gets set before you use it though.

This works.

```
let a: Bool

a = true

if a { // Compiler happy

}
```

This works as well, because `a` is guaranteed to be set.

```
let a: Bool

if thingOne < thingTwo {
    a = true
} else {
    a = false
}

if a { // Compiler happy

}
```

However, this would not work because `a` is not guaranteed to be set before you try to use it.

```
let a: Bool

if thingOne < thingTwo {
    a = true
}

if a { // Compiler NOT happy
    // "Constant 'a' used before being initialized"
}
```

Now, if you can't guarantee that your variable will be set by the time you do the check, then you should really be using an optional `var` in the first place.

```
var a: Bool?

if a == true { // Compiler happy

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. The main reason I couldn't get rid of my ! is because I am using an ObjectMapper https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper and it is recommended to use the ! in this situation.

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to say if using `!` is appropriate in your case. There definitely are some weird situations with JSON serialization in particular. `NSJSONSerialization`, for example, cannot handle optionals and instead requires the `NSNull` object. Depending on what you're doing there and how ObjectMapper works, it might be necessary.